# Cannot install libpostgresql-jdbc-java

Tags: postgresql

I have a VM running Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I am trying to install libpostgressql-jdbc-java as root:

```
apt-get install -y libpostgresql-jdbc-java
```

This produces the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libpostgresql-jdbc-java
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list contains these lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

I never modifed the configuration. It's a clean install with updates applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm on the same server version, and `apt policy libpostgresql-jdbc*` tells me that there is a candidate for installation in Universe.

Comment: Yes, I found as much in a package description somewhere. Didn't know how to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to http://packages.ubuntu.com and search for your package:

> https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpostgresql-jdbc-java

Here you'll see you need the repository 'universe'.

> bionic (18.04LTS) (java): Java database (JDBC) driver for PostgreSQL **[universe]**

How?

> sudo add-apt-repository universe

if this is not working more manual:

> sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"

Regarding of your goals for this system, you'll may want to add also **restricted** and/or **multiverse**. And take a look at **partner**.

You can find more information about the details here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine), here (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/sources.list.5.html) or here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SourcesList).
Please stay at official sources and avoid to enable/activate/add PPA or any other 3rd party sources, unless you know what you are doing.